# Is it safe to comment out dependencies in a feature modules .info file?

Tags: 7, features, installation

I used features to migrate config and content (with uuid features) from a dev site to a live site.

Now its there, I dont want the features anymore. Or perhaps partly, but I'd rather rebuild the features on the live site from scratch.

However, if I disable a dependency in the feature, that thing - content, content type, menu, whatever - actually gets removed from the system. As intended. But I dont want that.

Is it safe to just comment out all dependencies from the feature modules .info file ?

Comment: Safe in what respect? Dependencies are essentially used to stop modules being installed/uninstalled without code they rely on it that relies on theirs. If you remove a dependency, you need to check manually that it won't have a negative impact. You'll also need to ensure no one disables these modules manually, now that you've removed the only integrity checking that Drupal is able to do. The answer is always "it depends", really. Probably not a good idea

Comment: 'Safe' databasewise: in the sense that the features module doesnt at some point change the database or other modules due to a changed .info file. It is exactly the 'integrity checking' I want to get rid of, or change, without changing the installation.